# Difference between Slope and Gradient

Tags: calculus, terminology

It has been a few years since studying contour maps.

Often I hear slope and gradient interchangeably in describing steepness.

Does anyone know any good definitions and analogies of slope and gradient.

Thanks,

Amanda

Comment: Depending on the country you live in, 'gradient' is the same as 'slope'. Here's an example of the use of 'gradient' in the UK: [Finding the gradient of a straight line](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/algebra/graphsrev4.shtml). I had never heard of the term 'slope' until high school when I watched Khan Academy videos, and read textbooks published in the US.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Best Answer - Chosen by Voters
>
> A gradient is a vector, and slope is a scalar. Gradients really become meaningful in multivarible functions, where the gradient is a vector of partial derivatives. With single variable functions, the gradient is a one dimensional vector with the slope as its single coordinate (so, not very different to the slope at all).
>
> Source(s):
> Currently studying multivariable calculus

Comment: It's good to [cite your sources](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081129031556AAsze9X).

Comment: *Scalars* can be vectors too! :P

Comment: @BillyRubina ??

Answer (score 7):

Contour maps graph level curves of a given function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. A parametrization $(x(t),y(t))$ of the level curve $f(x,y)=k$ satisfies $f(x(t),y(t))=k$. Differentiating with respect to $t$ yields the following by the chain rule,
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}=0 $$
Therefore, the gradient $\nabla f = \langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \rangle$ is perpendicular to the tangent vector $\langle x',y'\rangle$ of the curve when we compare them at a particular point.

Comparing slope to $\nabla f$ directly is geometrically questionable since $y=f(x)$ is a graph whereas the natural context for the gradient is in the study of contours. For a graph $z = f(x,y)$ the tangent **plane** has normal $\pm \langle \partial_x f,\partial_y f,-1 \rangle$. The natural analogue to the normal of the tangent plane would be the slope or perhaps the direction vector of the normal line $y=f(a)-\frac{1}{f'(a)}(x-a)$.

Slogans:

1.) the gradient points in the direction for you to level-up

2.) the derivative is the slope of the tangent line

To really understand you must separate the concepts of the graph of a function and level curves. These are related but they are not the same object.

Answer (score 3):

> Often I hear slope and gradient interchangeably in describing steepness.

This is because gradient and slope can mean the same thing. This depends on which part of the world you live in.

> Gradient: (Mathematics) The degree of steepness of a graph at any point.
>
> Slope:  The gradient of a graph at any point.
>
> Source: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gradient)

Gradient also has another meaning:

> Gradient: (Mathematics) The vector formed by the operator ∇ acting on a scalar function at a given point in a scalar field.
>
> Source: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gradient)

Be aware that gradient can mean two different things in mathematics.

Answer (score -1):

As gradient is a vector and the gradient of a scaler is a vector ie it drives a scaler in a direction; slope is a scaler ( scaler can be positive and negative) yet it drives a line ( y= mx+ c ) with unique steepness in upward or downward in a direction ( deviation depends upon change in perpendicular per unit base ie tan(theta) which is proportional to theta and up and down  direction by + and - signs) unlike a vector which has finite length (magnitude)

Comment: Welcome to math.SX! If you answer a four years old question which already has good answers, make sure that your answer actually adds something to the discussion.