# Given a function $f(x,y)$ how to get the points where the tangent has a certain given slope?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, tangent-line

For example let the the function given be $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ slope given be 2.
My first intuition would be getting the gradient of the function which would be $2i+2j$ then setting it equal to the given slope and solving such that:
$2i+2j=2$
Then this looked to me that I am considering the gradient the same as the tangent which is wrong as they are perpendicular
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190756/difference-between-slope-and-gradient) will be usefull in order first to get acquainted with the definitions.

Comment: This is a function of two variables, so you have a tangent plane. What do you mean by a tangent and its slope in this context?

Comment: May be the OP want to mean gradient vector